# How to solve Runtime error in Android bin res crunch directory?

Tags: android, eclipse

I am using eclipse(3.7.1) for android development. When i try to run the application it showing error in bin-->res-->crunch directory

Please any one help me to resolve this error

Comment: What is the specific error?

Comment: nothing is showing in loggat just red error symbol in the specified directory when I run the code once cleaning it gone its coming on every run

Answer (score 7):

Try this, you must remove this folder in your Workspace and re-build your project:

- Go to /YourAndroidWorkspace/YourProject/bin and remove the "crunch" folder.
- Clear and re-build your project in Eclipse.

It´s work for me.

Answer (score 1):

When building using the command line, Eclipse and ant could interfere.
(Especially if you use "build automatically")

For me it worked to close eclipse and run:

```
ant clean debug
```